# How to plot the annumber of particles in the distribution

Tags: python

I've generated a 2D histogram.
[image]

Can anyone explain me how can I proceed to divide it into different bins and then integrate each bin to calculate the number of elements it contains?

I've used this function *bins = plt.hist2d(s1, s2, 100) * to generate the 2D histogram, so I know that I have 100 bins, but I don't know to cycle the different bins.

Thanks!

Comment: According to [matplotlib](https://matplotlib.org/api/_as_gen/matplotlib.pyplot.hist2d.html) docs `hist2d()` returns `h, xedges, yedges, image` with `h` being the matrix of the number of samples in each bin. You can hence iterate through `h` to access the various bins.

Comment: I've tried to do it, but what I get is an overlap of curves, of which if I make the fit I get a gaussian, but it's not what I should have. I understood how to move between the different bins of the 2D distribution, as you too suggest, just using xedges and yedges, but what I can not do is integrate the distribution, since I generated it with the function plt.hist2d (). In particular I should do the integral of a function that depends on two variables, both along the x axis and along the y axis, at the same time.